# Bug in the dropdown control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, default

I have a dropdown control, with some values I added in using the designer.

For example, "ANY", "Male", "Female".

The value for Male is set to M

The value for Female is set to F

The value for ANY is blank.

However, although it seems to be blank, I spent hours trying to debug a parse error...

And to my horror I discovered it wasn't blank at all! The value was set to "ANY".

I want the value to be blank, because my SQL query checks if the string is blank (or null).

My program breaks when it tries to put "ANY" into a varchar(1) for obvious reasons.

Am I doing something wrong? How can I make the default value blank?

Comment: Just an idea: What if you use a space instead of a blank string? This could be a special value, or you could just trim it.

Comment: If you don't explicitly set a value then the value is set to that of the text property.

Comment: Problem was I edited the items using visual studio editor. If you leave the value blank in the editor, it does not put Value="" into the code, which is what caused my problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set Value=""

```
<asp:DropDownList id="DropDownList1" runat="server">
   <asp:ListItem value="" Text="ANY">
   </asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

If you still have your bug just set the value to 0 or one letter

Answer (score 1):

You can have a blank value, you can reference it like this:

```
DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
```

**OR**

```
DropDownList1.Text;
```

Comment: Doesn't the Text property get and set the same value that the SelectedValue property does?

Comment: You are correct, I just read the docs.  I will edit the answer.